# hw to make my iframe follow all media queries according to viewport

Tags: html, css

**update**
The problem is with the @media tag, I used multiple as I've seen others done to make the iframe  resize depending on what device the website is viewed on. I was fiddling with the code not too long ago and found out that the iframe is only obeying the values in the last media query at any view size, even though I give them each a different min width.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry I couldn't understand your question correctly but if you're trying to make your iframe permanent at a place in wrapper then apply value of fixed to position property.